# Spring Integration with Twitter Issue with Authentication

Tags: spring, twitter-oauth, spring-integration

I am trying to post a message to my twitter account using **Spring Integration with Twitter** with a standalone program on my windows XP machine. But I am getting the following error -

```
WARNING: POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.twitter.outbound.StatusUpdatingMessageHandler#0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at com.skilledmonster.spring.integration.twitter.TwitterOutbound.main(TwitterOutbound.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.social.RevokedAuthorizationException: The authorization has been revoked. Reason: Unknown
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterErrorHandler.handleClientErrors(TwitterErrorHandler.java:96)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterErrorHandler.handleError(TwitterErrorHandler.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:294)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.twitter.outbound.StatusUpdatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(StatusUpdatingMessageHandler.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is my code -

**twitter-outbound.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter/spring-integration-twitter-2.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.apress.prospringintegration.social.twitter" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="/twitter.properties" />

    <int:channel id="twitterOutbound" />

    <twitter:outbound-channel-adapter twitter-template="twitterTemplate" channel="twitterOutbound" />


    <bean id="twitterTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate">
        <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumer-key}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumer-secret}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${twitter.access-token}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${twitter.access-token-secret}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**TwitterConfigurationTemplate.java**

```
package com.skilledmonster.spring.integration.twitter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate;

@Configuration
public class TwitterConfigurationTemplate {
      @Value("${consumer-key}") 
        private String consumerKey; 

        @Value("${consumer-secret}") 
        private String consumerSecret; 

        @Value("${access-token}") 
        private String accessToken; 

        @Value("${access-token-secret}") 
        private String accessTokenSecret; 

        @Bean 
        public TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate() { 
            TwitterTemplate twitterOperations = 
                    new TwitterTemplate( 
                            consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret); 
            return twitterOperations; 
        } 
}
```

**TwitterOutbound.java**

```
package com.skilledmonster.spring.integration.twitter;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage;

public class TwitterOutbound {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/twitter-outbound.xml", TwitterOutbound.class);

        MessageChannel input = context.getBean("twitterOutbound", MessageChannel.class);

        Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<String>("Testing new Twitter samples for #springintegration"+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        input.send(message);

    }

}
```

**twitter.properties**

```
twitter.consumer-key=onj5cG1P9pe7n9qA8UI4EA 
twitter.consumer-secret=2l7hqMafKYaTkVBW3YfuBfGdzCtmICOJwjOOCEeQ 
twitter.access-token=792995125-dXmN1Pbw7sE4WttvAbX7ssxEn4lHaVd6uOX3IMxk 
twitter.access-token-secret=a1EuvvONcphdqXpfJVjCdaIBDlMZSUL5pgimWuEtg
```

FYI - I did test my twitter token and key with twitter4j and it seems to be posting the message to twitter successfully.

Here is my code with twitter4j -

**OAuthSetup.java**

```
package com.skilledmonster.spring.integration.twitter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Calendar;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
public class OAuthSetup {
  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
      Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

//insert the appropriate consumer key and consumer secret here

      twitter.setOAuthConsumer("onj5cG1P9pe7n9qA8UI4EA", 
          "2l7hqMafKYaTkVBW3YfuBfGdzCtmICOJwjOOCEeQ");
      RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
      AccessToken accessToken = null;
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      while (null == accessToken) {
        System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
        System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
        System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
        String pin = br.readLine();
        try{
           if(pin.length() > 0){
             accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
           }else{
             accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
           }
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
          if(401 == te.getStatusCode()){
            System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
          }else{
            te.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
      //persist to the accessToken for future reference.
      System.out.println(twitter.verifyCredentials().getId());
      System.out.println("token : " + accessToken.getToken());
      System.out.println("tokenSecret : " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
      //storeAccessToken(twitter.verifyCredentials().getId() , accessToken);
      Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Testing new Twitter samples for springintegration # "+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
      System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
      System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue was with the empty spaces in the key values in the properties file :-)

Here is a [full example](http://www.skilledmonster.com/frameworks/spring/integration/spring-integration-with-twitter-how-to-post-tweets-to-your-twitter-account/) on my blog.

Comment: Link-only answers are problematic, because they become useless if the link goes down. Please move the relevant information from your blog post into your answer here so that it can stand by itself. You can then offer the link for additional information if people want it.

Comment: @Brad - I believe I already did that! The core issue was with the empty spaces at the end of the property key value pairs in the properties file. Which is what I have already mentioned. And then gave a link to my blog with full example! Let me know if this needs to be changed!

Answer (score 0):

The token you are using to access Twitter has been revoked, or possibly not valid for the consumer id / application id you are using.

`org.springframework.social.RevokedAuthorizationException: The authorization has been revoked`

You will need to perform a new authorisation to obtain a token and secret for use with your application, or alternatively, on the twitter application configuration page (https://dev.twitter.com/apps/) you can generate a token specifically for your personal usage. This is useful for testing an app conveniently without having to perform OAuth.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different consumer id and secret than before?

Comment: Is your application definitely registered with the twitter account you are trying to use? https://twitter.com/settings/applications I'm wondering if the way you are capturing the OAuthtoken using Twitter4j is correct? I've used the spring-social-quickstart as a basis to write my own token acquisition and it is performed wholly within the web browser.

Comment: Both versions of the code is already posted above. Twitter4j works absolutely fine! Although the difference is for twitter4j user intervention is required to punch in then key to get secret token..but when I use spring, I don't need that because I already know my secret token from my twitter account.

Comment: That's the bit I don't understand, can you not try your auth token and secret in the twitter4j example directly without attempting to obtain it each time from Twitter. Perhaps when you request it using the PIN, it is refreshed and changed?